# Convert string decimal to int

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a string "246246.246" that I'd like to pass to the IConvertable interface, ToInt16, ToInt32, ToIn64.  What is the best way to parse a string with decimal places to an integer?

This is a solution, but is there a better solution?

```
string value = "34690.42724";
Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDouble(value));
```

Comment: Are you concerned with rounding at all or just trimming the decimal portions?

Comment: Always use CultureInfo when you convert strings to numbers.

Comment: Rounding to the nearest whole number would be fine.  Most of the time it will be stuff like 99.99999999999 and I want to round to 100.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To do this discounting rounding you could do:

```
Convert.ToInt64(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(value)));
```

If you need to round you could replace `Math.Floor` with `Math.Round`.

**Edit:** Since you mentioned in a comment that you'll be rounding:

```
Convert.ToInt64(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(value)));
```

If you have to worry about localization/globalization then as @xls said you should apply a CultureInfo in the conversions.

**Edit 2:** Alternative method using a string function (not terribly elegant IMO - maybe it could be elegantized with a predicate function):

```
Convert.ToInt64(value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf('.') > 0 ? value.IndexOf('.') : value.Length));
```

Comment: So it sounds like there isn't any special way to do this.  You just Covnert() then Convert() again.

Comment: @Mike - Sometimes the shortest distance between two points is a straight line. At some level you have to convert. You could possibly shorten it with some string functions.

Comment: You should not have to Round the value as ToInt64(double) returns the rounded version already

Comment: what is the package for Convert? what should i import?

Comment: @vaibhavcool20: It's in the System namespace. `using System;` should get it done.

Answer (score 17):

You should not have to Round the value as ToInt64(double) returns the rounded version already

```
        string value = "246246.246";
        Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDouble(value));
```

Comment: It won't round correctly, ie. 23.5 will become "23" instead of "24"

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen `Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDouble("15.5"))` return 16 as per ms docs and a quick test. It rounds, not truncates.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really worry about accuracy but not about speed then decimal type would be better.

```
(long)Math.Round(decimal.Parse(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this string comes from user input, you probably want to catch number styling. Run it through a reusable function like so...

```
int? ConvertToNumber(string value)
{
   if (value == string.Empty) return null;

   try
   {
       var dec = decimal.Parse(value,
           NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint |
           NumberStyles.Number |
           NumberStyles.AllowThousands);

       return (int)Math.Round(dec);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Please input a number.");
       return null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below is to convert decimal Amount to Kobo value, which is needed when integrating to a payment gateway needing the amount in kobo's or cent.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{          
  decimal amount = 50.567890m; 
        
  int koboValue = 0;
        
  String[] values =  amount.ToString("0.##").Split('.');
        
  int wholeNumber = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
        
  if(values.Count() > 1){
        koboValue = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join(string.Empty,values));
  }else{
        koboValue = wholeNumber * 100;
  }
        
  Console.WriteLine(koboValue);
}
```