# I want to be able to handle decimal places within my listbox. 

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

I want to be able to handle decimal places within my listbox.

```
List<int> listInt = new List<int>();
listInt.Add(Convert.ToInt32("5.7"));
textBox1.Clear();
listBox1.Items.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < listInt.Count; i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(listInt[i]);
}
```

Using the code above I get an error: **Input string was not in correct format.**

I tried reading this: [C# Convert String Decimal to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975613/c-sharp-convert-string-decimal-to-int)

Is there anyone out there who understands parsing a decimal to a listbox?

**EDIT to Buh Buh code:**

```
    listDecimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text));
    textBox1.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < listDecimal.Count; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(listDecimal[i]);
    } 

    textBox1.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < listDecimal.Count; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(listDecimal[i]);
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
    CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt arrayOfInt = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt();
    arrayOfInt.AddRange(listDecimal); // error here!
    string result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt);
    label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);


}
```

Using the decimal rather than Int I now get an error in my code

This line:

```
arrayOfInt.AddRange(listDecimal);
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert a double into a integer list while preserving the decimals? I don't understand what are trying to do here.

Comment: Do you get an exception or does it just do something different than you hoped?  Define "use"?

Comment: Im trying to insert decimal numbers into listbox: I get an error if I try say 64589.4568 Input string was not in correct format.

Comment: Not sure why I have been given a down vote its quite self explanatory

Comment: I don't think you are being very clear and precise. For instance, how is `listInt` defined? What can users enter in `textBox1`? Have you tried simply adding strings representing decimal values to your list box?

Comment: List<int> listInt = new List<int>(); Users can only enter numerical values with decimals. I think my question is quite clear.

Comment: Not sure how else I could have worded that I cant seem to add decimal numbers to my listbox?

Comment: @Garrith It doesn't really matter how clear _you_ think it is, unless you are happy to be downvoted and not allow people the chance to answer you effectively.  I still don't know what your desired output is.  If I type "5.7" into your textbox would you like the output to be "5" or "5.7" or "6" or something else?

Comment: Also, one way of making a question clearer is to reduce it to it's simplest form.  If you have once method call that is throwing an exception you should post only that method call.  We don't need to read up on your whole project to know how to parse an int.  Also, using a textbox as input is complicated; you might have typed absolutely anything into that textbox.  It would be must clear to just use a string literal, such as "5.7".

Comment: Ok give me a second Buh Buh I will re phrase the question as obviously the complicated nature of adding an decimal point into a listbox needs a dialogue of biblical nature ;)

Comment: One more way of making your questions clear is to edit the question to take into account the comments.  For example once roymustang86 and Bernard pointed out your mistake of not defining listInt, it would be nice for you to correct your question.  As it stands you are asking each individual reader to work through all the comments and piece together what you probably/maybe meant to ask.  While you are doing that you could also fix your broken layout.  No biblical nature required; a short, _accurate_ question would be better.

Comment: Done? Any better? I thought it was one of those solutions everyone had understood/came across and could quickly correct. Hope it is more helpful now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
listInt.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)));
```

The problem with ToInt64 is that it makes a long and you want an int.

If that doesn't work you can do

```
int index = textBox1.Text.indexOf(".");
int value;
if(index != -1) {
    value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text.substring(0, index));
}
else {
    value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
}

listInt.add(value);
```

To get the location of the decimal point and then read in the number up to that point

I assumed because you were using a list of integers that you wanted an int at the end of the parsing after talking to you it seems like you want a double so the following should accomplish that.

```
List<Double> listDouble = new List<Double>();
listDouble.Add(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text));
```

Comment: yeah i tryed int32 but it cuts the decimal places off instead. I will give the other one a try.

Comment: Sorry indexOf was IndexOf damm capitals lol! Erm I tryed that method but nothing adds to the listbox now? No errors either? So not sure whats happend.

Comment: what do you want to be in the list when it's done? Also did you ever add the value variable to the list because in my code above the value is just parsed it isn't added to the list you still have to do `listInt.Add(value);` to add it.

Comment: Also the snippet of code will also truncate the number into an integer.

Comment: Yeah I need it not to truncate the number both methods only input 4896 and not 4896.586 like im typing.

Comment: If you want the number to be 4896.586 for example you have to change the type of `listInt` to be a list of doubles and then add use the `Convert.ToDouble` to convert. This will make the number a double and keep the whole number. If you want to round it use `Math.Round` instead of `Math.Floor`

Comment: Hey Twain same error I get with Buh Buhs code my arrayofint wont work in the edit area of my updated post.

Comment: That's because you are trying to use an int adding method to add numbers that are not integers you'll have to change everything, that uses this, from integers to doubles or to decimals.

Comment: There is no such thing as CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfDoubles tho?

Comment: you should be able to do a `double sum = 0; foreach(double d in listDouble) {sum += d;}` to sum the values and the a `label1.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);`

Comment: I don't know C# very well so I don't know if there is an ArrayOfDouble version. But the code in the comment above should some a list of doubles for you.

Comment: Yup you solved that problem for me sorry I forgot to accept the answer. New question is here on sending it via soap tho if you know how to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570791/list-to-handle-array-of-decimals

Answer (score 1):

An integer is a whole number.  Integers do not have decimal places, so it sounds like you probably don't want to be using them at all.  I have adapted your question to use the class Decimal instead.

```
List<decimal> listDecimal = new List<decimal>();
listDecimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal("5.7")); 
textBox1.Clear(); 
listBox1.Items.Clear(); 
for (int i = 0; i < listDecimal.Count; i++) 
{ 
    listBox1.Items.Add(listDecimal[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks buh buh is there a way to change an arrayofint to decimal (see updated post and code)

Comment: Once a number is converted to an integer, the decimal places are lost and are not coming back.  You can convert from an integer back to a decimal but the decimal part will always be `.0`.

Comment: :O so there is no way around this?

Comment: If you are happy to lose the decimal places then do something like `var integers = listDecimal.Select(d => (int)decimal)); arrayOfInt.AddRange(integers);`.  If you really need the decimal places then you must change the type of `arrayOfInt`.

Comment: I really need them, what can be used other than array of ints?

Comment: Array of decimal? `decimal[]`