# list to handle array of doubles

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, soap, decimal

Is there a way to handle a list of doubles I can handle ints with the code below but not sure how to handle array of doubles.

```
    {
CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt arrayOfInt = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt();
arrayOfInt.AddRange(listDouble); // error here!
string result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt);
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);

    }
```

This is all wrong tho I need instead of ArrayOfInt to have Array of double?

Client Side:

```
    namespace CalculateSumOfList
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

            List<Double> listDouble = new List<Double>();


            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
            private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                listDouble.Add(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text));

                textBox1.Clear();
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < listDouble.Count; i++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(listDouble[i]);
                } 

                textBox1.Clear();
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < listDouble.Count; i++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(listDouble[i]);
                }
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
                CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt arrayOfInt = new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt();
                arrayOfInt.AddRange(listDouble); // error here!
string result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt);
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);



            }



        }
    }
```

Web Method:

```
namespace CalculateWebServiceSum
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]


        public string CalculateSum(List<double> listDouble)
        {
            return listDouble.Sum().ToString();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<double>` is perfectly valid. It would help if you included the exact error/problem that describes why this (supposedly) doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yup List<double and decimal> are fine. But when I try send this using soap from the client I only have one option CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt there is no arrayofdoubles so on the line I mentioned in my code I get the error

Comment: Sorry folks I completely messed this question up and got confused I have fixed the question now and hopefully should make alot more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear what your question is, but:

If `arrayOfInt.AddRange( listOfDouble )` is not compiling you could use Linq and do

```
arrayOfInt.AddRange( listOfDouble.Select( d => (int)d ).ToList() );
```

The method client.CalculateSum expects a parameter of type `List<double>`

1) I would change that if possible to be `public string CalculateSum(IEnumerable<double> items)` which is more flexible

2) As above you can convert a list of any convertible type using `list.Select(n => (double)n).ToList()` assuming that `(double)n` is a valid cast.

Comment: Sorry I really messed the question up I had to redo it.

Comment: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:3048/Service1.asmx. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. On this line: string result = client.CalculateSum(arrayOfInt);

Comment: Thats using this method: arrayOfInt.AddRange( listDouble.Select( d => (int)d ).ToList() );

Comment: So the problem is nothing to do with lists etc.  Reduce your code to the simplest possible test case.  Remove the body of the service method.  Call the method with a known value.  Then build up from there.

Comment: Ok got it all working the IEnumerable was causing a serilization problem. But I have a new problem even altho its all working the sumation I used from the webservice isnt adding up the decimals?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly, you need to call [ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) to a type of decimal before you can add the listOfDecimal.

```
var convertedDecimalList = arrayOfInt.ConvertAll<decimal>
    (element => (decimal)element);
convertedDecimalList.AddRange(listDecimal);
```

UPDATED:

```
CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client = 
    new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt arrayOfInt = 
    new CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ArrayOfInt();
var listOfIntAsDouble = arrayOfInt.ConvertAll(x=>Convert.ToDouble(x));
listOfIntAsDouble .AddRange(listDouble);
string result = client.CalculateSum(listOfIntAsDouble);
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match if I try that? On convertedDecimalList.AddRange(listDecimal);?

Comment: Is arrayOfInt really an array of ints? If so, then you will have to use arrayOfInt.ToList().ConvertAll. If not, what is your specific error?

Comment: Sorry no an array of doubles.

Comment: I was trying to solve two problems at the same time and confused myself

Comment: Looking at the update to your question, why can't you just use ConvertAll using a double? Or whatever type you are trying to convert to?

Comment: CalculateSumOfList.ServiceReference1.ConvertAll? Doesnt Exist?

Comment: If I try  arrayOfInt.ConvertAll(listDouble); I also get an error

Comment: string result = client.CalculateSum(listOfIntAsDouble); error on this line best overload method again