# How to convert string to int?

Tags: asp.net

How to convert string to int?I know convert.ToInt32 is used.But it fail.Error is input string is not in proper format.
String s1 = "12.00"

Comment: 12.00 is not an integer, its in decimal format!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*error is because string is `"12.00"`*

first convert string to double than in int

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble("12.00"));
```

or

IF you just want integer part of it than

```
string s= "12.00";
string[] words = s.Split('.');
int a = Convert.ToInt32(words[0]);
```

Also check already answered threads on SO : [C# Convert String Decimal to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975613/c-sharp-convert-string-decimal-to-int)

Answer (score 6):

I love the assumption that the decimal separator always is a dot (`.`). You'd better use the [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx), which contains a NumberFormat that explicitly specifies the dot as a decimal separator:

```
Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble("12.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

To clarify: [half the world uses the dot, the other half a comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark). When I run this on a PC with a Dutch culture and do not specify a CultureInfo, it takes the system default (comma) and returns `1200`, ignoring the dot.

While it does not directly affect your problem, it is something that can't be stressed enough.

Answer (score 3):

"12.00" is a decimal number, not an integer. Integers don't have fractional portions. Use [`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble.aspx) or similar to get a floating-point number, or trim off the decimal part of the string (the `.` and what follows) prior to calling `Convert.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 1):

The string "12.00" is a double/decimal value. Use Double.Parse() or Double.TryParse() or Convert.ToDouble().