# Decimal point in "Convert.ToInt" statement causing Format Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STad7hn4EEk&list=PLHcT1fP9Jq8NSmmmaWumC8z4LEDfNPYJG&index=14) to help me create a basic shopping basket. When trying to run the code with the below method added which should calculate the TotalPrice & TotalProducts of the basket on the OrderForm, I get the following error:

> 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

pointing at the line

```
long ProductPrice = 
    Convert.ToInt64(PriceLabel.Text) * 
    Convert.ToInt64(ProductQuantity.Text);
```

In the database, an example of a ProductPrice is "199.99" where as the tutorial only used whole numbers e.g. "199". I am not sure if this is what is causing the issue? If this is the case, how should the code below be modified to include the decimal point too?

I am new to coding, so this is really stressing me out, I really would appreciated some `guideance/suggested` code changes to overcome this issue

Thanks as ever guys!

```
private void UpdateTotalBill()
{
    long TotalPrice = 0;
    long TotalProducts = 0;
    foreach (DataListItem item in dlBasketItems.Items)
    {
        //Finds the price label on pnlMyBasket
        Label PriceLabel = item.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label;
        //Finds the quantity text box on pnlMyBasket
        TextBox ProductQuantity = item.FindControl("txtProductQuantity") as TextBox;

        long ProductPrice = Convert.ToInt32(PriceLabel.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantity.Text);

        TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ProductPrice;

        TotalProducts = TotalProducts + Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantity.Text);
    }
    txtTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice);
    txtTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalProducts);
}
```

**pnlMyBasket**

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlMyBasket" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" Height="500px" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1px" Visible="false">
    <table align="center" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="auto-style4">
                <asp:Label ID="lblAvailableStockAlert" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DataList ID="dlBasketItems" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" Font-Bold="False"
                    Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False"
                    Width="551px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div align="left">
                            <table cellspacing="1" style="border: 1px ridge #9900FF; text-align: center; width: 172px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="border-bottom-style: ridge; border-width: 1px; border-color: #000000">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName")%>' Style="font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img alt="" src='<%# Eval("ProductImageUrl") %>' runat="server" id="imgProductPhoto" style="border: ridge 1px black;
                                            width: 157px; height: 130px;" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                     <td>AvailableStock:&nbsp;                                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAvailableStock" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductStock") %>'
                                            ToolTip="Available Stock" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                         Price:<asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("ProductPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        &nbsp;<br /> Quantity Required x&nbsp;
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProductQuantity" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="10px" MaxLength="2" OnTextChanged="txtProductQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfProductID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <hr />                                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveFromBasket" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'
                                            Text="Remove From Basket" Width="100%" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1px"
                                            OnClick="btnRemoveFromBasket_Click" CausesValidation="false" />

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="33%" />
                </asp:DataList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

**pnlOrderForm**

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrderForm" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" Height="500px" BorderColor="Black"
                                    BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1px" Visible="false">
                                    <table style="width: 258px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                Name:
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerName" runat="server" Width="231px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerName"
                                                    ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                PhoneNo:
                                            </td>
                                        </tr
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerPhoneNo" runat="server" Width="231px" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerPhoneNo"
                                                    ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                EmailID
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerEmailID" runat="server" Width="231px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerEmailID"
                                                    ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                Address
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerAddress" runat="server" Width="227px" Height="81px"
                                                    TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerAddress"
                                                    ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                Total Products :
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalProducts" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="231px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTotalProducts"
                                                    ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                Total Price :
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalPrice" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="231px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTotalPrice"
                                                    ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                Payment Mode:
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left">
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblMethodOfPayment" runat="server">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">1. Collect & Pay In Store</asp:ListItem>
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">2. Pay with card</asp:ListItem>
                                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnPlaceOrder" runat="server" OnClick="btnPlaceOrder_Click" Style="font-weight: 700"
                                                    Text="PlaceOrder" Width="90px" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerEmailID"
                                                    ErrorMessage="Please Enter Valid EmailId" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Convert String Decimal to Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975613/c-sharp-convert-string-decimal-to-int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to convert to decimal, then to long. Like this:

```
long ProductPrice;
try
{
    // hey you never know, someone might just put in an int64 in that textbox!
    ProductPrice = Convert.ToInt32(PriceLabel.Text) * 
        Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantity.Text);
}
catch
{
    decimal tempPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceLabel.Text) *
        Convert.ToDecimal(ProductQuantity.Text);
    ProductPrice = Convert.ToInt64(tempPrice);
}
```

Comment: Hi @code4life...I tried this too, but get the same error in the catch section :( I wish I was able to share my screen with someone who understands it more than me! ha!

Comment: Hmm, what's the exception? Maybe either of the textboxes are empty? Just guessing here. BTW, I tested this in LinqPad and verified the code works...

Comment: Ah no way! :( So the Price should be called from the database, and the product quantity is set to 1 when first added to the basket. I just debugged the code and it says both values are 0, but the code is exactly the same as the tutorial video! :(  I am happy to share my screen if you would like to take a look (not sure if that's allowed here so apologies if not)

Comment: I'd say spend a few more minutes debugging through it. I'm sure you'll see where the problem is. I'm behind a bank firewall, so hard for me to interact any further...   ;-)

Comment: I have no go this to work - Just one problem. After the maths is done, the value that is put in the TotalPrice value is still rounded to the nearest whole number and doesn't show the decimal value e.g. 349".99" - Any ideas? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Most direct way to how you are currently doing:

```
 var ProductPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceLabel.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(ProductQuantity.Text);
```

this will throw an exception if the value cannot be converted to a decimal.  Decimal.TryParse() would be better.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have changed to this line of code, and still get the same error message :(

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see the values of PriceLabel.Text and ProductQuantity.Text?

Comment: I just did that and for whatever reason they are both showing as "null" Arghhh! This is the problem with being a novice! No idea why :(